# Python operator that mimic javascript || operator

Tags: python

I am Python newbie, so maybe don't knew if this is obvious or not.

In Javascript `a||b` returns `a` if `a` is evaluated to true, else returns `b`. 
Is that possible in Python other than lengthy if else statement.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe this is correct:

```
x = a or b
```

### Proof

This is how "`||`" works in JavaScript:

```js
> 'test' || 'again'
"test"
> false || 'again'
"again"
> false || 0
0
> 1 || 0
1
```

This is how "`or`" works in Python:

```py
>>> 'test' or 'again'
'test'
>>> False or 'again'
'again'
>>> False or 0
0
>>> 1 or 0
1
```

Answer (score 3):

In python you can use something like this

```
result = a or b
```

which may give you `result=a` if a is not False (ie not None, not empty, not 0 length), else you will get `result=b`

Comment: Basically it could be explained by showing these two statements as having the same effect: `result = a or b`, `result = a if a else b` (or longer: `if a: result = a [line break] else: result = b`). Upvoting anyway (for being correct).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do

```
a or b
```

For more complex logic (only for Python 2.5 and above):

```
x if a > b else y
```

This is the equivalent to the following which you may be familiar with from Javascript:

```
a > b ? x : y;
```

Answer (score 1):

`x = a or b` does the same thing.