# Pyspark error while execution

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
Rdd.filter(lambda x;x[1] =='red').collect()
```

It is working correctly. But,

```
Rdd.filter(lambda x;x[1] =='red'||x[1]=='black').collect()
```

Not working

> Error: invalid syntax

Comment: pretty sure all of it is invalid syntax because you have a semicolon where you should have a colon. If I had to guess, I think you are looking for: `Rdd.filter(lambda x: x[1] =='red' or x[1]=='black').collect()` which can also be expressed as `Rdd.filter(lambda x: x[1] in {'red', 'black'}).collect()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python operator that mimic javascript || operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111484/python-operator-that-mimic-javascript-operator)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `||` operator in python

Change it to `or`

```
Rdd.filter(lambda x: x[1] =='red' or x[1]=='black').collect()
```